# Add platform into vcxproj file with MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

how can I add new platform target into vcxproj file with MSBuild from Windows SDK without using the Configuration Manager from Visual Studio IDE ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify it inside any editor by hands - just copy/paste **PropertyGroup** with Condition on Configuration and Platform, change platform name and other parameters.

Comment: Do you know a tool to do it automatically from command line ?

Comment: As far as I know there is no such command line tool. But it can be easily written as a powershell or  msbuild script - just open proj as XML document use one query to find node, and one more to replace.

Comment: Second choice - from VS Configuration Manager - but it works unstable - With a very high probability you can loose your modifications.